# starling atf textures not displaying

Tags: actionscript-3, textures

So i'm running air 3.7, the latest starling frameworks, added -swf-version=20 -target-player=11.7 in compiler arguments and running the code

```
[Embed(source="/assets/wtf4.atf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private static const why:Class;

var data:ByteArray = new why();
var texture:starling.textures.Texture = starling.textures.Texture.fromAtfData(data);
var image:Image = new Image(texture);
addChild(image);
```

if I'm using the starling atf that came with the framework demo it works fine, but whenever i try to display my own png that I create in photoshop converted into atf it gives me a error saying

ArgumentError: Error #3677: Texture decoding failed. Internal error.

The image I'm trying to convert into atf is just a red square png with 512x512 sizes with the compiler arguments: png2atf -c -i example.png -o example.atf. I'm not sure whether my flash builder isn't setup to decode atfs or if i'm creating the atfs wrong for some reason, if someone could shed some light on this it would be awesome!

Comment: I don't want to discourage you from asking here, since it's a legitimate question, but you will likely receive a faster response on the Starling forum:  http://forum.starling-framework.org/

Answer (score 0):

When creating the .atf, did you created mipmaps also? If not, you need to set the second argument of the Texture.fromAtfData() function to false - don't use Mipmaps.

From Starlign wiki:

"If you omit mipmaps, you must set the parameter “useMipMaps” of the “Texture.fromAtfData()” method to “false”! Otherwise, you'll get a run-time error."

http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/atf_textures

Comment: I've tried both arguments for a variety of mipmaps, it doesn't seem to be the solution.

Comment: @user1573274 which tool do you use to make the aft file?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of ATF requires AIR 3.8 (which is currently in beta).  You need to download the AIR installer, and the latest AIR SDK.  More details here: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/error-3677-texture-decoding-failed-internal-error